# Display selected country option from solspace freeform - country select field in email notification template

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, solspace-tag

I have a contact form which uses the freeforms country select field. I also have a email notification template which I use to notify the admin. In this email notification template I display the selected country using {country} tag. The value displayed for the {country} tag is a short form of the selected country name. For example if 'United States' is selected, I get 'us' displayed in the email, but I want the full country name 'United States' to be displayed in my email. How do I do that? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added this to our road map on features to add (a parameter for country fields to control  output of value).

Comment: @Solspace, that will be great. But is there a work around for now?